# Villager trades rising from trading too much

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In my survival world all my villagers trade 1 stick for one emerald, and it has been like this for a while, but suddenly they demanded 2 sticks, then 3 for one emerald. I tried leaving the villagers alone for a few minecraft days, but the price didn't lower at all. Should I keep waiting or keep trading with villagers until the price becomes normal? What affects the villager trade mechanics? How do I decrease the price from trading too much?

Answer (score 2):

If you keep buying over 50% of trades for a specific item from a village, the price will rise. If you don't buy for a full in game day while the villager was capable of selling (in loaded chunks, restocked), the price will fall back towards the one set as 'standard' by permanent positive bonus (like after curing the villager from zombification).

My guess regarding why the price didn't fall after you left them alone is that you left for some other tasks in a different part of the world, your trading hall unloaded and as result no time was passing for the villagers. Spend the time near the villages (be it idling AFK or doing whatever within ~8 chunks from them) and the price should fall the same amount it has risen over the same amount of time trading with them. And once it's down, either only trade 50% of the max volume, or mark half of the hall and switch between the two halves ever day you trade, exploiting one to 100% while letting the other half 'lie fallow' recovering the prices.